# CSV to SAS dataset: no line-final comma causes problems

Tags: csv, sas

I'm trying to import a .CSV file into a SAS dataset, and am having some trouble. Here's a line of sample input:

```
Foo,5,10,3.5
Bar,2,3,1.0
```

The problem I'm having is that the line-final "3.5" and "1.0" are not being correctly interpreted as variable values (instead SAS complains that they are invalid values, giving me a `NOTE: Invalid data for VARIABLE` error). However, when I add a comma to the end of the line, like so:

```
Foo,5,10,3.5,
Bar,2,3,1.0,
```

Then everything works fine. Is there a way that I can make this import work without modifying the source file?

Currently, my DATA step's INFILE statement has the `DSD`, `DLM=','`, and `MISSOVER` options.

Comment: If you post your code we can see if there are any other problems you are missing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This most likely has to do with the different codes for [line endings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations) in Unix and Windows. I'm guessing your data comes from a different operating system than the one you're running SAS on.

The solution is to change the newline codes to the correct operating system. If you're running SAS on a unix system, try the `dos2unix` command. If you're running Windows, you can edit the CSV file with a text editor like UltraEdit or Notepad++ and save the file in Windows format.

Comment: This appears to have been it -- I `dos2unix`'d my input file and SAS stopped throwing that invalid data error.

Is there a way that I can do this without directly editing the source? If not, then that's alright, but I would prefer to leave the source file untouched.

Comment: You could try the TERMSTR option on the infile statement

Answer (score 3):

With this data in a .csv file in a windows environment

```
Foo,5,10,1.5
Bar,2,3,2.1
Foo,5,10,3.5
Bar,2,3,4.1
```

This code works (running SAS locally on a windows machine)

```
filename f 'D:\Data\SAS\input.csv';
data input;
 infile f delimiter=','; 
 input char1 $ num1 num2 num3;
Run;
```

As @itzy mentioned, the environment is important..more info will help with the solution

When you are working with data from a different environment, you can use the [TERMSTR option on the INFILE statement](http://support.sas.com/techsup/technote/ts673.pdf) to tell SAS how the lines of data are terminated.